# Saving a cookie for darkmode/lightmode JS - Issues

Tags: javascript, cookies, darkmode, lightmode

I am trying to make the cookie load when the body does, and then check what value it is. If darkmode = true, then it should display css/cssmain.css. If it is false, it should display css/csslight.css. The cookie works: If I use the button to switch from dark to light, it changes darkmode from true (dark) to light (false) and vice-versa. It even stays when I refresh the page, but the css switches to its default file.

Basically, I can not figure out how to make darkMode go into the if statement in my javascript. I tried it with onload="getCookie(darkMode)" to try and put the cookie darkMode's value (true or false) into the script. It seems to just not run the script, because even if I add an alert, the alert does not pop up when I use the button.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Freshwater Fish</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cssmain.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/desktopview.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slides.css">
    <link id='css_theme' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/csslight.css'>
    <script src="js/fullstackfrog.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getCookie(darkMode)">

<button  class="lightmodeButton" onclick="document.getElementById('css_theme').setAttribute('href', document.getElementById('theme').value, document.cookie = 'darkMode=true'); if (document.getElementById('theme').value == 'css/cssmain.css'){  document.getElementById('theme').value = 'css/csslight.css'; document.cookie = 'darkMode=true';} else{ document.getElementById('theme').value = 'css/cssmain.css'; document.cookie = 'darkMode=false';}">Light/Dark</button>
<input type="hidden" id="theme" value="css/cssmain.css">

</body>
</html>
```

JS (fullstackfrog.js):

```
function getCookie(name) {
  if (name) {
    document.getElementById('theme').value = 'css/cssmain.css';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('theme').value = 'css/csslight.css';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how cookies work? `document.cookie` will just stay the same. You need to write something to get the cookie and parse the value from `document.cookie`. Try reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie and use the examples.

Comment: The cookie doesn't stay the same. It changes everytime you click the button.

Comment: I meant that the string `document.cookie` will stay unchanged (will not revert) when you refresh or change the site.